# Angular ui-select model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I have following object in the scope

```
$scope.myData = {};
$scope.companies =    [{name:'Microsoft',slug:'micro'},
                {name:'Google',slug:'gg'}];
```

I am trying to bing slug to model by using ui-select

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Company</label>
    <ui-select ng-model="$parent.myData.company" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a company in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="company in companies | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="company.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

However when I select a company, myData.company becomes full object such as.  `{"name":"Microsoft","slug":"micro"}` How can I bind `slug` of company object to myData.company but able to search by company name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to do it thanks to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices#example-binding-single-property) In order to make it work,  `<ui-select-choices>` should be changed as follows;

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="company.slug as company in companies | filter: $select.search">
```